# Does anyone could help me find some references about term "The Schouten bundle"?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles

I`ve been doing many google search and It seems that there´s no information about it, but just the reference of the Dutsch Mathematician Jan Arnoldus Schouten.

Comment: In what context did you see this term?  I don't think I've ever heard of such a bundle.

Comment: Where did you hear/see the term? I am aware of the Schouten bracket but not the Schouten bundle.